# tqdm notebook - 2 inner bars

Tags: python, pytorch, training-data, tqdm

I'm trying to print training progress bar using tqdm.
I'd like to track the progress of the epochs, and for each epoch i have 2 progress bars: the train_loader minibatches, and validation_loader minibatches.
The code is something like that:

```py
for epoch in tqdm(range(epochs_num)):
    for inputs, labels in tqdm(train_loader, "Train progress", leave=False):
        # train...
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in tqdm(validation_loader, "Validation progress", leave=False):
            # calc validation loss
```

Using the `leave` argument, the progress bars deleted every epoch, but I'd like to delete them **togather**, right after the validation process ends.
There's any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse your progress bars and do the updates manually like this:

```
epochs = tqdm(range(epochs_num), desc="Epochs")
training_progress = tqdm(total=training_batch_size, desc="Training progress")
validation_progress = tqdm(total=validation_batch_size, desc="Validation progress")

for epoch in epochs:
    training_progress.reset()
    validation_progress.reset()
    
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        # train...
        training_progress.update()
        
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels in validation_loader:
            # calc validation loss
            validation_progress.update()
```

If the batch sizes are not always the same, you can calculate them on the fly and call `reset(total=new_size)`.